# Performance comparison between hadoop Pseudo-Distributed Operation and Standalone Operation

Tags: performance, hadoop, distributed

I'm a very beginner of hadoop. But I had this interesting observation.

Using [the example](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r1.0.2/single_node_setup.html) in hadoop documentation,

By running the same example in Standalone Operation and Pseudo-Distributed Operation, the standalone one took less than 1 minute but Pseudo-distributed operation took more than 3 minutes. This is big difference. I could understand there are extra network and scheduling overhead in distributed mode. But the difference just seems to be too much. This may not be a real comparison because the example is very simple.

My question is, how much difference did you experience between the standalone and distributed mode for a real-world job?

Comment: Neither pseudo-distributed or standalone mode is intended to be used in production, so it may be difficult to get a useful answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

These are reasonably different scenarios. In stand-alone mode, it never starts up a proper one-node Hadoop cluster. Everything happens locally, inline, in the JVM. Data never has to be even written out to disk, potentially. Pseudo-distributed operation is the smallest "real" Hadoop installation, of one local node. You have to read/write data to a local HDFS instance, spawn another JVM, etc. All of that adds a lot of overhead. Maybe the overhead is indeed a few minutes. This seems entirely sensible to me.

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop frame work is meant for processing BIG DATA..

**So the size of the data matters a lot** ,because ,a smaller file would get processed in traditional file system very quickly than in hadoop because hadoop mapreduce frame work has internal work to do (to make chunks of data file and to send it to data nodes and while processing again access from data nodes ).So for a smaller files ,hadoop frame work is not suitable.

Coming to standalone and pseudo distributed mode ,one aspect u should consider is size of the file and second being actual difference in standalone and pseudo distributed mode.

In standalone mode there is no concept of HDFS,data is not copied to hadoop distributed  file system (obviously time saved).Where as in pseudo distributed mode ,hdfs involved which need to be copied with the data that's need to be processed.

**Small size data files better to use traditional file processing and if the file size become huge and huge ,hadoop framework gives better processing time!**
Hope this helps!

Comment: This needs serious editing. Break it into paragraphs and use formatting where appropriate.